# Retrieving entire line from a socket in C#?

Tags: c#, python, sockets

I have a simple client-server system sending plain text - though only commands that have been approved. The server is a Python system - and I've confirmed proper connections.

However, the client is C# - in Unity. Searching for examples, I stumbled across this bit of code. It does seem to do what I want, however, only partially:

```
public String readSocket()
{
    if (!socketReady)
        return "";
    if (theStream.DataAvailable)
        return theReader.ReadLine();
    return "";
}
```

The strings I am sending end with \n, but I'm only getting half the message like this:

Message A:

1. claim_2

Message B:

1. _20_case
2. claim_1

I know this probably has to do with how I'm directly reading the line but I cannot find any better examples - strangely enough, everyone seems to point back at this snippet even when multiple people point out the problems.

Can anything be done to fix this bit of code properly?

In case it helps, I'm sending the information (from my Python server) out like this:

```
action = str(command) + "_" + str(x) + "_" + str(userid) + "_" + str(user)
cfg.GameSendConnection.sendall((action + "\n").encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: The problem is.... you might not have enough data available to actually read a complete line.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Here's an assumpion: You're using a `NetworkStream` and a `StreamReader` to read that `NetworkStream`. `StreamReader`'s `ReadLine()` reads up to a newline _or until there is no more data in the stream_, whichever comes first. In sockets programming, it is important to note that when you `send(some_data)`, that data might be split up into several packets. The receiving end might receive that data in small chunks. Whenever the first chunk arrives, the stream has `DataAvailable`. So it reads. Up to the end of the data that is available, which may be part of a message ending with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

When you do sockets programming, it is important to note that data might not be
available in one piece. In fact, this is exactly what you are seeing. Your
messages are being broken up.

So why does `ReadLine` not wait until there's a line to read?.

Here's some simple sample code:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true };
writer.Write("foo");
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
```

Note that there is no newline at the end. Still, the output of this little
snippet is `foo`.

*`ReadLine` returns the string up to the first line break or until there is no
more data to read.* The exception being reading from a stream that has no more
data to read, then it returns `null`.

When a `NetworkStream` has its `DataAvailable` property return true, it has
data. But as mentioned before, there is no guarantee whatsoever about what that
data is. It might be a single byte. Or a part of a message. Or a full message
plus part of the next message. Note that depending on the encoding, it could
even be possible *to receive only part of a character*. Not all character
encodings have all characters be at most a single byte. This includes UTF-8, which `cfg.GameSendConnection.sendall((action + "\n").encode("utf-8"))` sends.

How to solve this? Read bytes, not lines. Put them in some buffer. After every
read, check if the buffer contains a newline. If it does, you now have a full
message to handle. Remove the message *up to and including the newline* from the
buffer and keep appending new data to it until the next newline is received. And
so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I process the entire line in my similar application, which is a very simple code, and your code may be different, but you can get the idea.

```
private string incompleteRecord = "";
public void ReadSocket()
{
    if (_networkStream.DataAvailable)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[8192];
        var receivedString = new StringBuilder();
        do
        {
            int numberOfBytesRead = _networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            receivedString.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
        } while (_networkStream.DataAvailable);
        var bulkMsg = receivedString.ToString();

        // When you receive data from the socket, you can receive any number of messages at a time
        // with no guarantee that the last message you receive will be complete.
        // You can receive only part of a complete message, with next part coming
        // with the next call. So, we need to save any partial messages and add
        // them to the beginning of the data next time.
        bulkMsg = incompleteRecord + bulkMsg;
        // clear incomplete record so it doesn't get processed next time too.
        incompleteRecord = "";
        // loop though the data breaking it apart into lines by delimiter ("\n")
        while (bulkMsg.Length > 0)
        {
            var newLinePos = bulkMsg.IndexOf("\n");
            if (newLinePos > 0)
            {
                var line = bulkMsg.Substring(0, newLinePos);
                // Do whatever you want with your line here ...
                // ProcessYourLine(line)

                // Move to the next message.
                bulkMsg = bulkMsg.Substring(line.Length + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                // there are no more newline delimiters
                // so we save the rest of the message (if any) for processing with the next batch of received data.
                incompleteRecord = bulkMsg;
                bulkMsg = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```